# Exception in thread main com.inet.ora.Ora3SQLException:[OraDriver] java.net.UnknownHostException:@localhost

Tags: jdbc

hi The below code is getting compiled but there is run time error as:

```
"Exception in thread main com.inet.ora.Ora3SQLException:[OraDriver] java.net.UnknownHostException:@localhost"
```

code:

```
import java.sql.*;
class CreatingTable
{
    public static void main(String[] ar) 
        throws Exception{DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.inet.ora.OraDriver())
    Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:inetora:@localhost:1521:orcl","riya","java");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    int students=stmt.executeUpdate("create table class(name varchar2(20),rollno number(20)");
con.close();
}}
```

here I have used inet jdbc driver,please anyone get me the solution for this....

Answer (score 0):

Try removing @ from localhost
`"jdbc:inetora:localhost:1521:orcl"...`